# Camunda synchronous process instance wont suspend

Tags: process, synchronous, bpmn, camunda, suspend

I would like to suspend an synchronous running process instance if I encounter some error to give admin some time to rectify the error and then he can resume the process instance using its id.

I am trying to suspend a running process instance from java delegate class but it does not seem to suspend.

Below is my code -

```
public class Generate_DT_PS_CCS implements JavaDelegate {

   @Override
   public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
            RuntimeService runtimeService = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRuntimeService();

            String pid =execution.getProcessInstanceId();
            System.out.println("supending the instance - process id " +pid);
            runtimeService.suspendProcessInstanceById(execution.getProcessInstanceId());

   }
}
```

Is there any issue in suspend the synchronous service task in Camunda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not interact with your processInstance through the runtimeService API if your processInstance has not been saved to the database.
That's why it is always a good practice to make the start event async, then you can be sure that there is an entry in the db.
So this is not an issue of suspension.